# Code within .join().then() not executing

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here's the issue I have.
When I type `!join` my bot joins the correct voice channel as expected. However the `console.log("Successfully connected.");` message doesn't appear. Any code I put within the body of `join().then(connection => { //code here});` isn't executing.

If I type `!join` a second time while the bot is already in the voice channel the bot will say `console.log("Already connected");` which is correct.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the `join().then()` method?

I'm using the exact example shown in the discord.js documentation https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/VoiceConnection

NOTE: All of this code is wrapped within an `async` function as follows `bot.on("message", async message => {// code here. });`

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}join`) {
  let channel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "bot-commands");
  if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
    if (!message.guild.me.voiceChannel) {
      message.member.voiceChannel.join()
      .then(connection => {
      // Code here doesn't execute, but the bot still joins.
      // All code here should execute when the bot joins a voice channel.
        console.log("Successfully connected.");
      }).catch(e => {
        // This error isn't being thrown when the bot joins.
        console.log(e);
        });
      } else {
        // This will execute when I type !join when the bot is already in the VC.
        console.log("Already connected");
     }
   }
 }
```

Here is my package.json as well

```
{
  "name": "discordbottest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "discord.js": "^11.3.2",
  "ffmpeg-binaries": "^3.2.2-3",
  "opusscript": "0.0.6"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

Tried using `await` as suggested:

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}join`) {
  let channel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "bot-commands");
  if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
    if (!message.guild.me.voiceChannel) {
      console.log("Before connection"); //This line is executed.
      let connection = await message.member.voiceChannel.join();
      console.log("After connection"); //This line is not executed.
    } else {
      console.log("Already connected");
      return message.channel.send("Hello! I'm already here!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's weird, it seems like you wrote it in the right way...
Can you try putting the `voiceChannel.join()` in an async function and then using await: in this way if you put a `console.log` after it we'll see if that promise resolves or not.
Does this happen everywhere or only in this spot?

Comment: Hey @FedericoGrandi. I should have mentioned, the `voiceChannel.join()` is already within an async function. Every example I found used one so I thought that might have been assumed, sorry about that.

Comment: @FedericoGrandi As for the `await` I had tried that as well, I've added that code to the end of the original post if you want to see. Maybe I did something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: That's interesting... This means that, even if the bot joins the channel, the `join()` promise is never resolved, but neither rejected as you say that the catch statement does not run. First, try to check if you're using the lastest discord.js at master, then check if you have other libraries that could cause problems with discord.js or that can modify the [ClientVoiceManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/ClientVoiceManager).
If the error still happens after that, I suggest you to get in touch with the devs, either via Discord or GitHub, since this could be a serious bug.

Comment: Let me know how this ends

Comment: Oh wait [you already did](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2652)

Comment: @FedericoGrandi Good news everybody! I I found the problem. Turns out the network I was on was rejecting the connection. I'll explain. I've been developing this bot during my spare time at work. Turns out my work's networking is blocking voice connection on Discord. When I connect to a voice channel I get a message saying RTC Connecting and eventually it says "No Route".

Comment: So I hot-spotted my work laptop off of my phone and I was able to get it to work!

Comment: Good, remember to write the problem as an answer to this question & accept it.
Also, remember to close your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2652)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was an issue on my local machine. I was developing this bot during my spare time at work and I found out that my work's network was stopping voice channel connections from fully completing. When I joined a voice channel myself it would get stuck saying "RTC Connection" followed by "No route" and would loop between those two messages. I tested the bot at home and it worked without any problem. Thank you all for the suggestions throughout this, I was able to learn more about discord.js :)